# How to fix 'sharing to instagram stories' in iOS 13 using URL Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, instagram-api, url-scheme, uipasteboard

I have implemented sharing to insta stories which are working fine for iOS 12 but not working on iOS 13.

I have tried/verified following points

- Verified URL Scheme
- Checked changes to UIPasteBoard
- Verified asset urls

Everything is as per documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/

```
if schemeAvailable(scheme: "instagram-stories://share"){
                let pasteboardItems = ["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage":UIImagePNGRepresentation(postImage!)!,
                                       "com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL":"http://google.com"] as [String : Any]
                UIPasteboard.general.setItems([pasteboardItems])
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "instagram-stories://share")!, options: [:], completionHandler: { (finished) in
                    print("")
                })
            }else{
                print("Can't open URL")
            }
```

Comment: How do you make `com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL` to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved my issue and i was messing in info.plist.

make sure that you have added `instagram-stories` in `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` not in `URL Schemes`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that **"com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL"** parameter has become unavailable or private.

There is one workaround how you can proceed working with text/url described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74241318/20343737

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33056072)